# Lex not recognizing VOICE input for AMAZON.EmailAddress

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex, alexa-voice-service

The input for an email address works for while testing with "Test bot" or via SMS message input.
But for the voice command, it has trouble recognizing for example "**tony@gmail.com**"
So do I spell it out to Lex by " **T O N Y @ G M A I L DOT C O M**" or say "**tony@gmail.com**"?
If I say "**a@gmail.com**" it seems to recognize that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is sometimes a formatting problem between how Amazon Connect/Lex interprets Voice-To-Text before attempting to fill a specialized slotType like email. So you should check how Lex is receiving each one of your voice inputs using [AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/).

And because of this, you will probably need to build your own email parsing and validation code in Lambda and fill the slot yourself, focusing on parsing the Voice-To-Text output format variations.

This is why your direct text inputs are working because Lex can parse them easily. But I'm sure you will see some strange formatting in voice input emails that won't work well in Lex's AMAZON.EmailAddress slotType parser.

Once you can view how Voice-To-Text interprets your tests, you should be able to see a pattern that you can build your own simple parser for and then your Lambda can then handle both text and voice inputs well.

Comment: If I print the event such as print(event) you can see the response from the user. However when I look in the section inputTranscript (*If the input was an audio stream, the inputTranscript field contains the text extracted from the audio stream. This is the text that is actually processed to recognize intents and slot values.*) there is nothing there.   So do I need to SAY the entire emailaddress or spell it out for Lex?

Comment: Yes that's all correct, but wait, "there is nothing there" In inputTranscript? That is unexpected to say the least. You SHOULD be able to compare inputTranscript which is the voice-to-text with the slots confirmation and you can see what Lex was interpretting and how it filled the slot from the input. But if inputTranscript is empty.....that may be a different issue.

Comment: The mic registers and you can use it in other parts of your Lex bot? When it gets to email, does it trigger the Error Handling response? If not, how does you bot respond when inputTranscript is empty?

Comment: Let me correct what I said. On a few times, YES the "there is nothing there" but that depends on how i input my email. That is why I was asking if I should say the email or spell it out. For example. I spelled out the characters of a email (example@gmail.com) and when I viewed CloudWatch I got ***inputTranscript': 'e. x. a. m. p. l. e. at gmail dot com*** - So let me give you credit for having me check that. Because from this I can parse what I need. So in summary, it looks like I should SPELL OUT the email vs. SAY IT